# Adding an Extra Code to Stored Procedure Without Modify

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

There is a stored procedure in MsSql. I want to add this stored procedure just one line of extra code but I want to do it in about 20 databases. So obviously I don't want to right click > modify each of them. I want to create a script to do this but the problem is, the modify script of this stored procedure is about 550 lines and I don't want to add all these lines just for one extra line to my upgrade script since there already is thousands of lines in the script.

I found such a solution; what it basically does is, it gets the create script of the stored procedure, finds a specific and unique line('append_5 = zr.append_5,') and replaces it adding the lines I want ('append_5 = zr.append_5, before_head = zr.before_head, before_body = zr.before_body,').

```
Declare @prDefinition nvarchar(MAX); 
SET @prDefinition = (select  object_definition(object_id) proceduredefinition from sys.procedures where name = 'cms_asp_approval_approve_zone_revision')
IF CHARINDEX('append_5 = zr.append_5, before_head = zr.before_head, before_body = zr.before_body,',@prDefinition) <= 0
BEGIN
SET @prDefinition = REPLACE(@prDefinition,'append_5 = zr.append_5,','append_5 = zr.append_5, before_head = zr.before_head, before_body = zr.before_body,')
SET @prDefinition = REPLACE(@prDefinition,'CREATE procedure [dbo].[cms_asp_approval_approve_zone_revision]','ALTER procedure [dbo].[cms_asp_approval_approve_zone_revision]')
EXEC (@prDefinition)
END
GO
```

This works fine, but this is of course the worst case scenario and is really unproffessional. What -more professional- ways do you have to solve such a problem?

**Edit :** I of course know creating an "ALTER" script would solve this, but it gives me 550 extra lines which I don't want. I want to have a shorter script.

Comment: Not quite sure if I've understood your problem correctly. Is your stored porcedure in all 20 databases the same and you need to apply the same changes?

Comment: Yes, exactly. They all are the same and I want to apply the same changes

Comment: Then just create alter script for your procedure in some database, apply your changes and then apply this script to all databases

Comment: Once again, this gives me about 550 lines of code, I don't want to have 550 extra lines in my upgrade script just to add one extra line

Answer (score 0):

You have some misunderstanding here. You can alter your stored procedure and it will be recreated exactly as you script it. It will not append to existing stored procedure it will change it:

```
create stored procedure spTest
as

select 1
select 2
...
select n
go
```

Then just alter your procedure:

```
alter stored procedure spTest
as

select 1
select 2
...
select n
select n + 1
go
```

Comment: But this gives me about 550 lines of code, I don't want to have 550 extra lines in my upgrade script just to add one extra line

Comment: You will have to or just use you current hack. Why is that restriction?

Comment: I already have thousands of lines. It is hard to control. And I don't have to since I have already achieved it with 5 lines of code. But I want to know if anyone knows better and more proffessional way

Comment: The only one way is to generate whole update script. What you are doing is just a hack, no one will guarantee that it will work tomorrow...

Comment: @EmreYıldırım professional way - is to keep things simple. For me - creating alter script manually is more simple and controllable way than doing some replacements over procedute text in sys.procedures and applying result.